# Kotlin optimize take first n elements with filter

Tags: kotlin

I have some `list: List <Pet>`
I need to take 3 elements from it that satisfy the condition:

I do it like this:

```
list.filter { g -> !mainList.contains(g) }.take(3)
```

How can you optimize this code so that the filter operation is executed no more than enough times for the result?

Comment: you can make a hashMap of mainList elements to true other <Object,Boolean> and otherwise its null, and after that use filter with hashmap[g]==true

Comment: mainList is a set, so there is no need to use another map here

Comment: ok then use for loop and if you get 3 elements count then break the loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [sequence](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html). Instead of fully processing each step in turn (i.e. create a new filtered list, then take 3 elements from that) each element passes through the chain, one at a time. So you don't create intermediate lists, and you can stop as soon as you get to the element that meets your terminating condition

```
list.asSequence()
    .filter { g -> !mainList.contains(g) }
    .take(3)
    .toList()
```

Note you have to execute the sequence (with `toList` in this case) to turn it into a concrete collection.

Also, as the link says, creating a sequence does introduce a bunch of overhead, so it's not necessarily more efficient - you'll see benefits with bigger collections, more steps in the chain, slower computation in things like the filter functions... anything where it makes sense to really minimise memory use or exiting early makes a big difference. You should benchmark it, make sure it's the right thing to do!

Also as a bonus, your filter operation could be `filterNot(mainList::contains)` if you like!

Comment: Another way of writing the filter is `filter{ it !in mainList }`.  (I find that way easier to read as well as shorter.  YMMV, of course.)

Comment: Oh yeah that's a good one, I like that better too

Comment: @gidds but `filterNot(mainList::contains)` as suggested in the answer as well is even better, I think

Comment: @WilliMentzel For me, any tiny difference in performance (if there is; I haven't checked) is outweighed by the greater readability and flexibility.

Comment: @gidds I think what is better readable is personal prference here. You're right about the flexibility, but when using modern IDE (Intellij) that's also not a real problem because they can convert it between the two forms. In the end, I think both is ok, I just lean more to the reference syntax :).